# Proper way to set model field values in EXT JS

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have the following model:

```
Ext.define('my.workspace.Area', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'id',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'width', type: 'int',getterName:'getWidth',setterName:'setWidth'},
        {name: 'height', type: 'int',getterName:'getHeight',setterName:'setHeight'}
    ]
});
```

If I instantiate this model, let's say like this:

```
var area = Ext.create('my.workspace.Area');
```

I am unable to use the setters setWidth and setHeight to set values to this instance. However I am able to do so like this:

```
area.set('width', someWidthValue);
area.set('height', someHeightValue);
```

My problem is that when this object is seralized to json via a save() or sync() invocation to store containing this instance I get:

```
...
"area": {
      "data": {
        "id": "someId",
        "width": 260,
        "height": 502
      },
...
```

instead of:

```
...
"area": {
        "id": "someId",
        "width": 260,
        "height": 502
},
...
```

And so my problem is the "data" entity in this json. I believe that his has something to do with the way I'm setting the field values in the area instance. Am I wrong to assume this? If not, what is the proper way to set these fields?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your question is the exact opposite of clear. How/why would you serialize data during "load" operation - ExtJS only deserializes during `load`, and serializes during `sync`.

Comment: That said, the official ExtJS docs do not show that a `setterName` or `getterName` config exist on `Ext.data.field.Field` at all.

Comment: I meant load/save operations to serialize/deserialize. I'll update the question

Comment: Can you please make a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/)?

Comment: Which ExtJs version do you use?

Comment: version 6.0.1.250

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert on this, but I hope this link would help
http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.Field.html

As I understand it, the [data] is part of the [Ext.data.Model] structure that you're extending.
the fields are accessible through the [data].

```
area.set('width', someWidthValue);
area.get('width');
```

if you want to use the setters such as setWidth you can define then as shown in the link above.